# How do transaction costs compare between Bech32 addresses and legacy Bitcoin addresses?

Tags: segregated-witness, transaction-input, address-format, bech32-address

Now that Electrum 3 supports Bech32 addresses for segwit, when sending coins to a legacy address are fees higher or cheaper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Transfer from Legacy ⟶ SegWit: pay full fee (doesn't benefit from [SegWit discount](https://medium.com/segwit-co/what-is-behind-the-segwit-discount-8515a8d3bca9))
- Transfer from SegWit  ⟶ Legacy *or* SegWit: discounted.

**Note:** SegWit addresses can be [Bech32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki) `bc1...` or they can be [nested](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#p2wpkh-nested-in-bip16-p2sh) in a legacy P2SH `3...` address which are backwards-compatible (although less efficient). Many exchanges, wallets support the legacy "nested" form only.

Answer (score 2):

In general spending from a segwit output (i.e. "sending from" a segwit address) will be cheaper than spending a non-segwit output (i.e. "sending from" a non-segwit address). So yes, if you "send from" a bech32 address, it will be cheaper than "sending from" a P2PKH address.

Comment: My coins are on mycellium now and I'm assuming I can't send these coins to a bc1 address. How do you suggest I move it into electrum? Do I just do a sweep?

Comment: Import your seed phrase into Electrum and send from there. Or use Electrum to sweep your coins.