# SegWit transaction fee/byte

Tags: transaction-fees, segregated-witness

For transaction not spending SegWit outputs it's straightforward: if I have `1000` Satoshi fee set for `500` byte raw transaction, I end up with `2` s/b fee.

How about transaction containing witness data?

Say, my raw transaction is `500` bytes,`100` bytes of which are witness data. Thus, `400` bytes are now competing for the place in 1 Mb block.

How accurate is it to say that current transaction fee is `1000 / 400 = 2.5` s/b?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Say, my raw transaction is 500 bytes,100 bytes of which are witness data. Thus, 400 bytes are now competing for the place in 1 Mb block.

That's not correct.

SegWit replaces the concept of size and maximum block size with **weight**. The weight of a transaction is defined as 3 times the stripped_size in bytes (excluding the witness) plus the total_size in bytes (including the witness). The maximum weight of all transactions in a block is 4000000. This is the only limit that matters. Due to the way the weight formula is constructed, it implies that the old rule (stripped_size <= 1000000) is always satisfied. Miners try to get as much fees out of the weight limit they have available, and as a result optimize for *fee per weight*.

So, transaction sizes don't matter anymore. What matters is their weight. Unfortunately, there is a factor 4 scaling between the two, so you can't easily convert feerates from before SegWit to after. For this reason, the concept of **vsize** (virtual size) was introduced. It's equal to weight/4. For non-SegWit transactions, their size and vsize are identical. The easiest way to express fees is now to see them as BTC per vbyte (vsize byte).

> How accurate is it to say that current transaction fee is 1000 / 400 = 2.5 s/b?

In your example, the weight of your transaction is 3*400 + 500 = 1700. This means its vsize is 425 vbytes. As a result, its feerate is 1000 / 425 = 2.35 sat/vbyte, and it would compete with other transactions at that level.

Comment: As clear as it gets. Thx

Comment: @pieter-wuille Does Segwit embedded inside P2SH get the benefit of the new concept of size? The following question mentioned that using nested in a legacy P2SH has benefit (although less efficient). I want to understand the meaning.
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62053/how-do-transaction-costs-compare-between-bech32-addresses-and-legacy-bitcoin-add

Comment: Yes, it does, though to a lesser extent. I'll try to write an answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

- Legacy input size: 148 bytes (compressed)
- Legacy output size: 34 bytes (compressed)
- Segwit input size: 104 bytes
- Segwit output size: 32 bytes

so if your transaction has two inputs and one output total size is ~ 246 Bytes, Don't forget about some more additional bytes for transaction header.